# JQueryMobile: Custom icons

Tags: jquery-mobile, icons

I created a custom icon, when I assign it to a hard-coded list the custom icon shows. but when I place it to a programmatically added list in a table it doesn't show but instead displays the "plus" icon.

ironically when I try the "delete" built-in icon it properly shows but my custom made icon wont.

these are the scenario:

this is my custom button

```
 $(".ui-icon-customicon").css({'background-image':'url("http://website/mycustomeicon.jpg")','backgroundRepeat':'no-repeat', 'height':'18px', 'width':'18px', 'background-position':'center', 'background-color':'white'});
```

when I use the above button to a hard-coded list in a Table it properly shows. But when I use it like this...

```
listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.setAttribute("data-icon","customicon");
```

my icon doesnt show. and instead it displays the "plus" icon. but when I try this....

```
listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.setAttribute("data-icon","delete");
```

the button changes to the delete (builtin-icon) icon.
Anyone can help me whats the problem? please???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

> ***Updating lists*** 
>   If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the
>   refresh() method on it to update the styles and create any nested
>   lists that are added. For example,

```
$('ul').listview('refresh');
```

**Custom Icons**

> To use custom icons, specify a data-icon value that has a unique name
>   like myapp-email and the button plugin will generate a class by
>   prefixing ui-icon- to the data-icon value and apply it to the button.
>   You can then write a CSS rule that targets the ui-icon-myapp-email
>   class to specify the icon background source. To maintain visual
>   consistency, create a white icon 18x18 pixels saved as a PNG-8 with
>   alpha transparency.

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually, the above icon code works when I assign it to hard coded (eg. a Button). but when I try to apply it to a programatically/javascript injected object, the icon doesnt show which I am puzzled.

Comment: You might want to refresh it as well like this (updated answer): listItem.setAttribute("data-icon","delete").listview('refresh');

Comment: ok i will try this. thanks phill you always save me when i needed most. if this doesnt work ill make a jfiddle to show you how my code looks like.

Comment: hi Phil, yes I confirmed it and it works pretty well. thank you ver much man!